# java trust unix certificate store

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I have added a crt to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors so the server certificate can trusted by ssl clients. So, for example, when I `curl https://<server>` the certificate is trusted automatically.

Is there any way to make a java application to trust the certificates installed on the system?

Is the only way to make it works in java adding the certificate to the jvm truststore?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any out of the box solutions for that. I think there're multiple ways to reach your goal:

1. Write a class to sync you defined trust store and the cert directory
2. Write an own `TrustManager` implementation which is based on the cert directory

Answer (score -2):

Import it into the `cacerts` file in your JRE, and JDK if you have one.

Comment: _"Is the only way to make it works in java adding the certificate to the jvm truststore?"_

Comment: I recommend against changing Java's provided CA Certs, and instead specifying your own trust store.  Or as the answer with the most upvotes specifies, create your own TrustManager implementation.

Answer (score -2):

Import the certs in cacert file

Below is the path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin

use this code to import (assuming that your *.cer file name is abc.cer, you need to paste the abc.cer file in the bin folder then using the same path of bin in CMD run the below code) 
`keytool -import -file abc.cer -alias anyName -keysotre cacert -trustcacerts`

Comment: The OP is using Unix.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou thanks for the update, in this case, he/she need to use OpenSSL and set the environment variable to the particular path. Code remains the same

Comment: Do they have to run `keytool` every single time they upgrade their JRE or JDK? This is what the OP is evidently trying to avoid.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException see if the JDK or JRE is getting upgraded then it has its own cacert file in it. Either import the abc.cer again or copy the cacert file from the previous version and paste it in the path of the latest version. Ensure you take the backup of the latest cacert file

Comment: But that's just it. The OP wants one single system-wide keystore. There already is one on many unix-like systems, which is used by diverse tools and applications. Yet Java applications are an exception because to make them work you have to add the certificates to every JRE version on your system. It breaks the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.